# How to properly use parseInt to select/check a span element from within a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, parseint

I am attempting to use parseInt to determine if a span element is equal to or greater than 1 from within my Google Chrome Extension.

[I am attempting to check for this "0" to change and on change to launch a specific URL - See Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdSSp.png)

[Here is a screenshot of the "inspect" option from within chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKLAH.png)

Here is the page HTML:

```html
<div id="onlinebar" style="text-align: right">

 <a href="javascript:win1()" class="tb_options" title="Kalbėkis su savo piratais.">Užsuk į smuklę</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <span id="tb_gang" class="tb_options" onClick="ShowTbPopup(this); obShowHide(0)">My Fleet: (<b>2</b>)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <span id="tb_friend" class="tb_options" onClick="ShowTbPopup(this); obShowHide(1)">My Friends: (<b>2</b>)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <span id="tb_enemies" class="tb_options" onClick="ShowTbPopup(this); obShowHide(2)">My Enemies: (<b>0</b>)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <a id="closebox" href="#" onclick="javascript:var conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the login box? (It can be turned back on from settings)'); if(conf){ document.getElementById('onlinebar').style.display='none'; setBarPrefs('11769'); }" style="margin-right:20px;"><img src="/images/close.gif" border="0"/></a>

</div>
```

This is what I have tried:

```js
function checkEnemies(){
 numEnemies = parseInt($$("[id^=tb_enemies]")[0].title.split(" ")[0]);
 if (numEnemies >= 1){
  $$("a[href*='sea']")[0].click();
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}


var bool = checkEnemies();
```

And also this:

```js
function checkEnemies(){
 numEnemies = parseInt($$('#tb_enemies')[0].title.split(" ")[0]);
 if (numMessages >= 1){
  $$("a[href*='sea']")[0].click();
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}


var bool = checkEnemies();
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

-Shane

Comment: What's with the double dollar sign `$$`? Are you using jQuery? if so, it's just something like this `$('#tb_enemies')[0].title.split(" ")[0]` instead.

Comment: I also don't see a `title` attribute on the `span` element with id "tb_enemies" in your screenshot so your not going to get a value from that code.

Comment: From the picture, it seems that the element with ID `tb_enemies` doesn't have a `title` attribute, also, instead of using images you should include the HTML in text form and make sure you include it all (the image is missing the actual number).

Comment: Thanks for comments, I went back and added the HTML by editing my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number doesn't seem to be set as the value of the `title` attribute, you can get it directly from the element's content, here is an example:

```js
// jQuery

let number = parseInt($("#tb_enemies b").text());
console.log("jQuery the number is:", number);

// vanilla JavaScript

number = parseInt(document.querySelector("#tb_enemies b").textContent);
console.log("vanilla JavaScript the number is:", number);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="onlinebar" style="text-align: right">

 <a href="javascript:win1()" class="tb_options" title="Kalbėkis su savo piratais.">Užsuk į smuklę</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <span id="tb_gang" class="tb_options" onClick="ShowTbPopup(this); obShowHide(0)">My Fleet: (<b>2</b>)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <span id="tb_friend" class="tb_options" onClick="ShowTbPopup(this); obShowHide(1)">My Friends: (<b>2</b>)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <span id="tb_enemies" class="tb_options" onClick="ShowTbPopup(this); obShowHide(2)">My Enemies: (<b>0</b>)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <a id="closebox" href="#" onclick="javascript:var conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the login box? (It can be turned back on from settings)'); if(conf){ document.getElementById('onlinebar').style.display='none'; setBarPrefs('11769'); }" style="margin-right:20px;"><img src="/images/close.gif" border="0"/></a>

</div>
```

What this does is to get the text content of the first `<b>` element inside the element with ID `tb_enemies` and parse that text to an integer.

Comment: Thanks, I used a variation of this and it worked great.

I appreciate your time!